# Javascript Promise - fonfaceobserver + variable

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using fonfaceobserver to preload fonts.
I have this promise for the fonts:

```
Promise.all([
    marydaleBold.load(),
    interstateReg.load()

]).then(function() {

    console.log('Fonts are available');

});
```

But I would also like to check for a specific value of a variable & not just only if the fonts are loaded. How can I achieve this with Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Promise.all([
    marydaleBold.load(),
    interstateReg.load()

]).then(([marydaleBold, interstateReg]) => {

    console.log('Fonts are available');
    //And you can check for specific values in marydaleBold and intestateReg
});
```

This is called destructuring assignment, for more info, visit [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Thanks!
Well - unfourtunately there seems to be no support for this in IE so I won't be able to use this...

Comment: @NiklasWideC you can use babel in order to use it in IE.
If you're using gulp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel.

Comment: Please, if you found this answer useful, mark this as correct if you dont mind. Thank you.